# for loop function return outside function

Tags: function, loops, return, syntax-error

Hi guys could someone help me with this. I try to write a loop to get a list of number of word "END"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1REZo.png)

Comment: Where is the function declaration?

Comment: 'word = 'END'
count_end = []
for i in range(len(jnj)-1):
    sentence = jnj['headlines'][i]
    count = sentence.count(word) + 1
    count_end.append(count)
    i += 1
    return count_end'

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Please don't include code as image

Comment: Please consider adding a minimal reproducible example with an example of the desired output (in code form, not tables and pictures) to make it much easier for others SO users to find and test an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return it, if you just want to see the value of count_end you can add `print(count_end)` and that will output your list.

Also, for loops  in python will automatically add 1 to the variable you specified, so if you want to iterate over every element in that list you don't need the line `i+=1`

Final one, `for i in range(x)` will automatically stop at x-1, i.e. `for i in range(3)` goes through 0,1,2. No need for the extra -1.